# scraping a page that updates using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

It has now been weeks that I was trying to scrape all the information in [this](https://foolad24.com/profile/837) website. This website is the profile of a company and I'm tying to get all the information in this `id = "profile-basic"` section and `id="profile-addresses"` section.

> I am looping through 1000 0f these profiles and this is only one of them. The reason why Im not showing the code is because its very basic and it will not effect my question, though  for the ones that want to know its just a simple for loop that goes through a list one by one.

The problem is a lot of the elements in the page don't appear in some profile but in other profiles they will. I tried solving that by writing down the xpath of all possible elements and than using `try:` to check all of them and it worked just find, the only problem was the xpath would not always be for one part of information for example the xpath for addres `//*[@id="profile-addresses"]/div/div/div/div[1]/p` but sometimes it could be `//*[@id="profile-addresses"]/div/div/div/div[2]/p` many other xpaths. Since im trying to put the address inside the address variable it will be impossible to tell which xpath will be for the address in that page.

I tried using this code:

```
    names = {"آدرس تولیدی :" : "Address", "آدرس دفتر :" : "Address", "تلفن :" : "Phone2",
              "تعداد پرسنل :" : "StaffNumber", "کدپستی :" : "PostalCode", "توضیحات :" : 
              "Description2"}
    try:
        e=browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="profile-addresses"]/div/div/div/div[1]/span').text
        _1 = names.get(e)
        __1 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="profile-addresses"]/div/div/div/div[1]/p').text
        exec(f"global {_1}\n{_1} = Smalify('{__1}')")
    except:
        pass
    try:
        e=browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="profile-addresses"]/div/div/div/div[2]/span').text
        _2 = names.get(e)
        __2 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="profile-addresses"]/div/div/div/div[2]/p').text
        exec(f"global {_2}\n{_2} = Smalify('{__2}')")
    except:
        pass
    try:
        e=browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="profile-addresses"]/div/div/div/div[3]/span').text
        _3 = names.get(e)
        __3 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="profile-addresses"]/div/div/div/div[3]/p').text
        exec(f"global {_3}\n{_3} = Smalify('{__3}')")
    except:
        pass
    try:
        e=browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="profile-addresses"]/div/div/div/div[4]/span').text
        _4 = names.get(e)
        __4 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="profile-addresses"]/div/div/div/div[4]/p').text
        exec(f"global {_4}\n{_4} = Smalify('{__4}')")
    except:
        pass
    try:
        e=browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="profile-addresses"]/div/div/div/div[5]/span').text
        _5 = names.get(e)
        __5 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="profile-addresses"]/div/div/div/div[5]/p').text
        exec(f"global {_5}\n{_5} = Smalify('{__5}')")

    except:
        pass
```

The code above will read the span in front of the main element, and than find the matching variable name from the `names` dictionary and when it did it will se the value of the main element to the variable name using the `exec()` function.

> This code did not work at all for two reasons, A: It always returned Noun even if it could find the elements. B: It took way too long.

I was wondering if there is anyways **other than my code** to do it efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always try to search by ID, rather than xpath. Since the xpath is variable between the pages, try to find something that is static, such as ID name.

There is some more information about the different ways you can locate specific html elements using selenium at this [link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html). I definitely recommend checking it out.

Here is an example of searching for your elements by their IDs:

```
browser.find_element(By.ID, "profile-addresses").text
```

Good luck!

Comment: Is there any ways to get a list at return, I tried using `list(browser.find_element(By.ID, "profile-addresses").text)` but it make a list item for each character.

Comment: So it makes a list of characters in the string you are trying to grab? It would be hard to diagnose the problem without seeing the html of the site... I tried out the code on the link that you provided and it seemed to work properly. You could try using `browser.find_elements(By.ID, "profile-addresses")` to search for multiple HTML elements of the same ID, but I don't know if this will solve your problems.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of this, I finally fixed it. 